# Sequelize findOne-includes: conjunction table id is missing

Tags: many-to-many, sequelize.js

I want to query a Subject with Student with the join table included.
The relationship is many to many. I want to have the join table id (`StudentSubject`) but the returning result is empty

```
Subject.findOne({
            where:{id},
            include: [
                { model: Student, attribute: ['id', 'name']},
                { model: StudentSubject, attribute: ['id', 'subject', 'student', 'score'], as: "studentSubject"}
            ]
        })
```

The relationship is as follow

**student**

```
Student.belongsToMany(models.Subject, { through: models.StudentSubject, foreignKey: 'student'})
Student.belongsTo(models.StudentSubject, {foreignKey: 'id', targetKey: 'student', as: 'studentSubject'})
```

**subject**

```
Subject.belongsToMany(models.Student, { through: models.StudentSubject, foreignKey: 'subject'})
Subject.belongsTo(models.StudentSubject, { foreignKey: 'id', targetKey: 'subject', as: 'studentSubject'})
```

**the join table models**

```
// it has id by default in the migration file
const StudentSubject = sequelize.define('StudentSubject', {
    student: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    subject: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    score: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }
```

the result is missing the conjuntion table id, what do I miss here?

[image]

## additional experiment

tried also with nested include in Student, doesn't work. it doesn't have the id too

```
Subject.findOne({
            where:{id},
            include: [
                { model: Student, attribute: ['id', 'name'], include: [
                    { model: StudentSubject, attribute: ['id', 'subject', 'student', 'score'], as: "studentSubject"}
                ]},
            ]
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out I have to define the id in the conjunction table models. I thought otherwise, so here it is

```
sequelize.define('StudentSubject', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    student: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    subject: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    score: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }
```

and I incorrectly define the associations, so I came to this

```
Student.hasMany(models.StudentSubject, {foreignKey: 'student'})
Subject.hasMany(models.StudentSubject, { foreignKey: 'subject'})
StudentSubject.belongsTo(models.Student, {foreignKey: 'student', sourceKey: 'id'})
StudentSubject.belongsTo(models.Subject, {foreignKey: 'subject', sourceKey: 'id'})
```

and now when querying with

```
Subject.findOne({
            where:{id},
            include: [
                { model: Student, attribute: ['id', 'name'], include: [
                    { model: StudentSubject, attribute: ['id', 'subject', 'student', 'score'], as: "studentSubject"}
                ]},
            ]
        })
```

it now works

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this out but you may need to include the `id` of the `Subject` table in your first code block. The below may get you what you are looking for.

```
Subject.findOne({
        where:{id},
        include: [
            { model: Subject, attribute: ['id']},
            { model: Student, attribute: ['id', 'name']},
            { model: StudentSubject, attribute: ['id', 'subject', 'student', 'score'], as: "studentSubject"}
        ]
    })
```